# interchanged lens or interchanging lens?

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering what the right word to describe a camera lens that is replaced with another lens.

As I prefer to use the term "interchange", I put "interchanged lens" to refer to the lens replaced with the other lens. Then, can I say "interchanging lens" to refer to the other lens that is now in place of the lens that was originally attached to the camera?

Comment: How do you feel about "exchanged" and "exchanging" ?

Comment: You would say: "the other lens".  If, for some reason, you wanted to add an adjective (black, white, removable, automatic, expensive, antique, interchangeable, long, telephoto, etc) you would do so.

Answer (score 4):

To note the fact that the lenses are compatible and removable, the adjective to use would be [*interchangeable*](https://www.google.com/search?q=interchangeable+lens).

Using *interchanged lens* to refer to the lens that was removed is not appropriate.  The *inter-* prefix implies equality of treatment.  To refer to the lens that was previously mounted, you could say the *removed lens* or the *old lens*.  Or, you might come up with an alternative construction altogether:

> Be sure to cover the lens after unmounting it.

Answer (score 1):

Both lenses qualify to be called "interchanged" after the interchange. So that word is no help to distinguish between them at all (see below). 200_success has already noted the point.

We need to go beyond the term 'interchange' for that so as to be correct and unambiguous.

One simple way could be to call them the **Out-lens & the In-lens,** or such. **Old & New** is a classic option, too.

The lens that **has been replaced** is the old one, while the lens that **has replaced** is the new one.

There may be better alternatives.

---

Notes:

1. 'Change' is an external action and not an attribute of the object 'lens,' so it cannot be used to identify it. It is a different case (intransitive), though, when we say "He is a changed man." Here it is not so.
2. 'Interchange' requires two objects, so that both are candidates of the interchange.
3. Use of the past-tense alone is not enough. After the action of 'change' (or 'interchange'), it is equally past for both the lenses. Only the transitivity indicator will help: "is/has changed" *vs.* "has **been** changed."
4. However, 1 & 4 create a semantic problem due to the nature of the word 'change.' We may need to try 'replace' instead.

Comment: Do you not own an interchangeable-lens camera?

Comment: @tchrist No, I don't. However, that expression makes perfect sense. There the word 'lens' is a **class,** not a singular item. No need to tie oneself up in knots. :)